# Symfony 3 - Could not load type form type

Tags: php, symfony

I have just updated symfony from 2.7 to 3.0 and got some troubles with it..

It cant load my form types. Here is an example.

services.xml

```
app.search:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\SearchFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_search }
```

Thats how im trying to create form.

```
$form = $this->createForm('app_search', new Search());
```

SearchFormType

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class SearchFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder->add('phrase', 'text');
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_search';
    }
}
```

Getting next error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Could not load type "app_search"") in ....

How it should look like in symfony 3.0?

Thanks !

Comment: I know it sounds snarky but the first place to look is the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form.  You will notice that form aliases such as 'text' have gone away.  This is also mentioned in the upgrade file.  As well as a few dozen recent stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change your settings to..

```
app.search:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\SearchFormType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

And in your form type

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

    // ...
    $builder->add('phrase', TextType::class);
```

Then to call it use...

```
$form = $this->createForm(SearchFormType::class, new Search());
// or $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\Type\SearchFormType', new Search());
```

The long and short of it is that forms aren't named any more, they are referenced by the class name.

Comment: I have already tried that. Im getting An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not load type "text"")

Comment: See my admittedly snarky and unhelpful comment above.

Comment: yeah, it worked, i got it how it should work. Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 5):

I got stuck by this for about 2 hours today.  And the problem simply came from the namespace of the form type.  Instead of using `namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;` in your `SearchFormType.php` file, write `namespace AppBundle\Form;` .